# how come if you rub polythene with wool it gains electrons, but if you rub perspex with wool it loses electrons?

Tags: electricity

what makes a substance gain or lose electrons when it is rubbed with wool?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP shows no research efforts.

Comment: Im sorry. Im new in this site and I was wondering what I could do to make my question better for next time- what do I need to include?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just depends on the nature of the substance, or rather the valence electrons. If an object has less than 4 valence electrons then it will loose electrons, and become positively charged, just to complete the octet . If it has more than 4 valence electrons it will gain electrons and become negatively charged to complete the octet.

These are just properties of all materials. You HAVE to memorise them.

Comment: But perspex and polythene are both electronically stable already, and they are both unsaturated. Valence electron alone doesn't explain that. I'm not sure, but electrophilicity might explain it?

Comment: I am sorry. Valence electrons explains them all. Google- “Static electricity”.

Comment: It is called the "triboelectric effect" and there is a nice list and explanation in this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect